# Powershell unzip stream

Tags: powershell, stream

Is there a built-in cmdlet or some composition thereof that would allow me to start unzipping a file stream as each chunk is downloaded? I have a PowerShell script that needs to download a large (10 GB) file, and I have to wait until it is done right now before it starts expanding...

```
$wc = New-Object net.webclient
$wc.Downloadfile($appDataSnapshotUri, "%DataSnapshotFileName%.zip") # this can take some time

Expand-Archive -Path "%DataSnapshotFileName%.zip" -DestinationPath Run # so can this
```

Comment: I don't think the .zip compression file format works like that. (A partial download of a .zip file is a corrupt .zip file.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart is 100% right. The index is at the end of a zip called the central directory. Its where the metadeta but most importantly where the start point index of each file stored.

Comment: @ArcSet , @Bill_Stewart yes I have read this as well but I have also been able to do something like this in `nodejs` even if it is a bit hackerrific. So maybe try a compression format that better supports streaming decompression?

Comment: Is that file on a network drive or ftp or sharepoint? Can you share that node js script?

Comment: @MikeTwc sure, ill gist it, but for now just see https://github.com/mhr3/unzip-stream - i use this library

Comment: "So maybe try a compression format that better supports streaming decompression?" Right - you need a compression format that supports that.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Looks like that library assumes that zip file is already on the file system. did you make it work with byte stream you are getting over http?

Comment: @MikeTwc I think so, this is what was (I believe) working in nodejs https://github.com/jshin47/tagit/blob/master/web/server/jobs/unpackImportedImageZip.job.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out zip file doesn't need to be fully downloaded to be decompressed, you can compress/decompress streams. There is some built in capabilities in .Net for stream compression, but it will not work with zip archives. You can use SharpZipLib library for that:

Download .nupckg from https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/
Extract files to any folder. You'll need ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll  from lib/net45

Below is my simplified translation of their example:
https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#unpack-a-zip-using-zipinputstream-eg-for-unseekable-input-streams

```
Add-Type -Path ".\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll"

$outFolder = ".\unzip"

$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()

$zipStream = $wc.OpenRead("http://gitlab/test/test1/raw/master/sample.zip")

$zipInputStream = [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream]::New($zipStream)

$zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

$fileName = $zipEntry.Name

$buffer = New-Object byte[] 4096

$sw = [System.IO.File]::Create("$outFolder\$fileName")

[ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils]::Copy($zipInputStream, $sw, $buffer)

$sw.Close()
```

It will only extract first entry, you can add a while loop it this sample works.

Here is a snippet with while loop to extract multiple files (put it after `$zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()` on the example above):

```
While($zipEntry) {

$fileName = $zipEntry.Name

Write-Host $fileName

$buffer = New-Object byte[] 4096

$sw = [System.IO.File]::Create("$outFolder\$fileName")

[ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils]::Copy($zipInputStream, $sw, $buffer)

$sw.Close()

$zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

}
```

**Edit**

Here is what I found to work...

```
Add-Type -Path ".\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll"

$outFolder = "unzip"

$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()

$zipStream = $wc.OpenRead("https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/raw/master/FileGDB_API_1.5/FileGDB_API_1_5_VS2015.zip")

$zipInputStream = [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream]::New($zipStream)

$zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

while($zipEntry) {

if (-Not($zipEntry.IsDirectory)) { 
  $fileName = $zipEntry.Name

  $buffer = New-Object byte[] 4096

  $filePath = "$pwd\$outFolder\$fileName"
  $parentPath = "$filePath\.."
  Write-Host $parentPath

  if (-Not (Test-Path $parentPath)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory $parentPath
  }

  $sw = [System.IO.File]::Create("$pwd\$outFolder\$fileName")

  [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils]::Copy($zipInputStream, $sw, $buffer)
  $sw.Close()

}

$zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to tweak a bit to get it to work, but that's the idea. I'll share my tweak in an edit

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mike Twc's answer, a script to do it with and without stream, and compare how long it takes:

```
$url = "yoururlhere"

function UnzipStream () {
    Write-Host "unzipping via stream"

    $stopwatch1 =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()


    Add-Type -Path ".\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll"

    $outFolder = "unzip-stream"

    $wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()

    $zipStream = $wc.OpenRead($url)

    $zipInputStream = [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream]::New($zipStream)

    $zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

    while($zipEntry) {

    if (-Not($zipEntry.IsDirectory)) { 
    $fileName = $zipEntry.Name

    $buffer = New-Object byte[] 4096

    $filePath = "$pwd\$outFolder\$fileName"
    $parentPath = "$filePath\.."
    Write-Host $parentPath

    if (-Not (Test-Path $parentPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory $parentPath
    }

    $sw = [System.IO.File]::Create("$pwd\$outFolder\$fileName")

    [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils]::Copy($zipInputStream, $sw, $buffer)

    $sw.Close()
    }

    $zipEntry = $zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()

    }

    $stopwatch1.Stop()

    Write-Host "extraction took $($stopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds) millis with stream"
}

function UnzipWithoutStream() {

    Write-Host "Extracting without stream"

    $stopwatch2 = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $outFolder2 = "unzip-normal"

    $wc2 = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc2.DownloadFile($url, "$pwd\download.zip")

    $of2 = New-Item -ItemType Directory $outFolder2

    Expand-Archive -Path "download.zip" -DestinationPath $of2.FullName

    $stopwatch2.Stop()

    Write-Host "extraction took $($stopWatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds) millis without stream"
}

UnzipStream
UnzipWithoutStream
```